# Time Series Simulation Design

Tags: time-series, simulation

I want to Compare methods (Such as exponential smoothing methods, ARIMA models, artificial neural networks, grey-Markov model) to forecast short time series using a detailed simulation study.

How can I generate a simulated short time series data to compare the methods? OR, How can I get rid of the bias if using ARIMA models to generate simulated data?

Answer (score 1):

Write your own simulator ..there is no bias there as it is all you ! . I suggest that you inject anomalies (an example of a Gaussian Violation that needs attention ) to test the robustness of your candidate models.

Take a look at [Commonly used example data sets](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409991/commonly-used-example-data-sets/409994#409994) for challenging ways to create realistic data that nearly often defeats simple model-based approaches as compared to data-based approaches which evolve the model from the data.